# I can't create the object under my class for creating calculator

Tags: java, class, object, oop, program-entry-point

I have created a calculator class and a main method class under the same project. But in here for creating an object in the main method, it shows "actual and formal argument lists differ in length". I have attached the screenshot and also the java codes for both of my classes.

1. (Class file)

```
public class Calculator
{
     //instance variables
    private double num1;
    private double num2;
    private double result;
    private char operator;
    
    
    public Calculator (double a, double b, double r, char op)
    {
        //initialize instance variables
        num1= a;
        num2= b;
        result= r;
        operator = op;
        
    }
    
    public void setnum1(double a)
    {
        num1 = a;
    }
    
    public double getnum1()
    {
        return num1;
    }
    public void setnum2(double b)
    {
         num2= b;
    }
    
    public double getnum2()
    {
        return num2;
    }
    
    public void setoperator(char op)
    {
        operator = op;
    }
    public char getoperator()
    {
        return operator;
    }
    
    public void showcalculator()
    {
        System.out.println("Welcome!");
        System.out.println("1   2   3   +");
        System.out.println("4   5   6   -");
        System.out.println("7   8   9   *");
        System.out.println("0   00  .    /");
    }
    
    public String toString()
    {
        return ("First variable:"+ num1+ "/n Second variable:"+ num2+ "/n Result of"+ num1+ operator + num2+ "="+ result);
    }
    
}
```

2. (Main method file)

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class CalculatorTest
{
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        double a,b,r;
        char m;
        Calculator C1 = new Calculator();
        C1.showcalculator();
        System.out.println("Enter your first variable: ");
        a = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Input your second variable: ");
        b= input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Input the operator: ");
        m = input.next().charAt(0);
        C1.setnum1(a);
        C1.setnum2(b);
        C1.setoperator(m);
```

I tried to create an object for Calculator class

Comment: Create default constructor in Calculator class

Answer (score 0):

well, you need to read about constructor in java class.
when you define a constructor with at least 1 parameter, the default constructor (with 0 parameter) is disable, you need to write a new no parameter constructor.